# CSS: how to make the content are and footer sticky be responsive when user resizes it upwards

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the **content area** responsive when the user resize the browser upwards, as well I would like make the **footer sticky in the bottom** always.

**the problem:**

**1 -**when the user open this screen in other resolutions the footer disappear and the content area loose a bit of the content.

**2 -** if the user resize the browser window upwards the footer disapear and part of content area too.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0bc868hf/1/

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-header {
  background: green;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 17%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-left: 178px;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 78px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f6f9fb;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  header
</div>
<nav class="sidebar">
  sidebar
</nav>

<div class="content">
  content
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bc868hf/11/)

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
}

html { 
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
}

.navbar-header {
  background: green;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 178px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-left: 178px;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 78px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f6f9fb;
  position: fixed; bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 178px);
  left: 185px;
}
```

Comment: thanks vicent, I want this, the only thing is: the footer can't cover the sidebar udnerstand? need to be where it is but fixed, understand?

Comment: sorry i think i was not so clear, the footer needs to be the same size as the content is now, the footer can't be 100%, the footer needs to be sticky as the first example but fixed, understand? https://jsfiddle.net/0bc868hf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Look at this fiddle, I removed the `overflow: hidden` rules on the body and updated the rules on the footer class.

https://jsfiddle.net/0bc868hf/4/

Answer (score 0):

for the **.content**:

```
height: calc(100% - 150px);
```

for the footer:

```
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0;
```